# Adding links to SQLFORM.grid, Web2PY

Tags: python, database, web2py

```
def index():
gridHome = SQLFORM.grid(db.games, editable=False, create=False, csv=False, deletable=False, details=False, 
links = [lambda row: A('View Post',_href=URL("default","show",args=[row.id]))])
return locals()
```

I'm trying to add another link to the SQL grid just like the one above. I keep getting a syntax error as i don't know how to write it out.

```
'Review',_href=URL("default","review",args=[row.id]
```

That is the link i want to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were closing the global array before closing brackets of the link

```
def index():
    gridHome = SQLFORM.grid(db.games, editable=False, create=False, csv=False, deletable=False, details=False, 
                            links = [lambda row: A('View Post',_href=URL("default","show",args=[row.id])), 
                                     lambda row: A('Review',_href=URL("default","review",args=[row.id]))])       

    return locals()
```